# When do we use "typedef class xxxxx" in uvm?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm not familiar with uvm, but trying to understand and studying.

I found the below code when I leaning the UVM.

```
typedef class driver; 
typedef class monitor;   

class env; driver d0; 
monitor mon0;   
function init_drvr (); 
d0 = new (); // initialize endfunction   
function init_mon (); 
mon0 = new (); // initialize endfunction endclass
endfunction
endclass
```

Especially

```
typedef class driver; 
typedef class monitor;
```

Probably it seems like declare something, but why those typedef is in there?

Would you please let me know why do we use

```
typedef class driver; 

typedef class monitor;
```

and how to understand this grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rare that you would need `typedef class name` in SystemVerilog. Most programming languages require that identifiers used as type names be declared before they can be referenced syntactically. One place that occurs is if you have cyclical class references

```
class X;
  Y has_a_Y;
endclass
class Y;
  X has_a_X;
endclass
```

In order to compile the code for class `X`, class `Y` must be declared. If you change the compile order of the classes, then `X` becomes unknown. So we use what is called a **forward typedef**

```
typedef class Y;
class X;
  Y has_a_Y;
endclass
```

Now class `X` compiles as long as class `Y` gets defined before closing the current scope.

However, the UVM strongly discourages this kind of coding as these dependencies make the code less reusable.

Sometimes people use a forward typedef even when there are no cyclical dependencies because they are too lazy to compile their code in the correct dependency order.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **forward declaration** and is a feature of most object-oriented language compilers. It is used to declare an identifier that is not yet defined.

Basically, what you are telling the compiler is that there is a class called `monitor` and `driver` that is defined elsewhere in the compilation scope. This will be resolved at run-time.

For more info, refer to the below article: (it is in C++ but the concept applies)

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/